# MySQL CSV Import on Linux using Wizard

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am a SQL Server Professional, and trying to import a 5 million CSV file into MySQL. I have a very basic question, MySQL is on Linux Server and MS SQL server is on Windows. Can the operation be achieved by any MYSQL workbench Wizard?

Comment: Why don't you try it out and see for yourself?

Comment: I have tried out using command line, the data gets truncated eventually. Since it's urgent, a little help will be appreciated

Comment: Please add details regarding what you have tried (e.g. include the script you have executed) and what is the problem, including any errors that got trown.

Comment: The Load Data infile Script is working for the CSV Import to MySQL. The Export Import Operation for MySQL seems a little tedious.

Answer (score 0):

The Workbench is a very nice tool!  The Workbench Wizard should guide you through the steps.  Try it and you'll see how it works.